# Reopen vs delete and post it again?

Tags: support, asking-questions, closed-questions, edits

**What is the best practice?**

Edit your question and explain why it was closed wrongly and cast a vote to reopen.

or

Post an edited question explaining why it differs from another one and delete the previous question.

Consider that the question looks really similar to another one, but the problem is different it was closed by a single "SuperPoweredUser" and I believe it wouldn't change much if I deleted and posted it again.

I am asking because if the question goes through the reopening process it will have to wait before it can get any answers while the second "option" would make it answerable faster.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Deleting and re-posting is abusive. It smacks of trying to *evade* the evaluation of the community, and adds extra work for the people who look after the site.

If your reason for believing the close was in error is a good one, then a clear explanation should result in support.

Answer (score 6):

> Post an edited question explaining why it differs from another one and delete the previous question.

**This is a good way to dig yourself into a hole.** True story:

1. User post eminently closable question.
2. Question gets closed.
3. User deletes old question.
4. User posts old question as new question. (See below for a discussion of this step.)
5. New question gets closed.

So now they have two closed questions, probably with downvotes, which count against them in a possible question ban.

What's worse, the usual advice to get out of a ban is to edit old posts into shape. Okay so they edit the new question to get it reopened but what about the old one? They can't just apply the fixes they've applied to the new one because then the old one would be a duplicate of the new question and *still closable*. They could transform the old question into something completely different, I guess, but the transformed question would come onto the scene with the baggage of the old one (downvotes, for instance).

**They've essentially dug themselves into a hole.**

Ok, so **what's the deal with step 4?** Of course the worst approach would be to repost the exact same question, but you wisely avoid this possibility by saying that you'll post an "edited question". Still dangerous. Why? Because it often happens that edits do not actually take care of the problem that caused the question to be closed in the first place. (A too broad question remains too broad.) Or the edits fail to address everything that was problematic. (The question is no longer too broad *and* opinion-based but is still opinion-based.) Or the edits introduce a new problem. (A question that was originally unclear becomes too broad.) So if the edits fail in these ways then the new question will likely be closed.

Comment: Yes, I know what you mentioned. Did you, on the other hand, miss this part of my answer: 'you wisely avoid this possibility by saying that you'll post an "edited question"'? What I'm talking about is the case where you *think* you have taken care of the issue (because you've edited) but you in fact have *not* taken care of the issue. I see this happen again and again in the reopen queue, and I've seen it multiple times when people reposted their own deleted questions.

Answer (score 5):

Edit and vote to reopen. No need to post a new question.
But if your question was closed, then some reasons stay behind it?